# With PHP, how to retrieve items that match created month and year

Tags: php, mongodb, unix-timestamp

I'm using this code to retrieve news items from my MongoDB:

> foreach (collection("news")->find(["created"=>$time]) as $news)

Now I would like to find only those news articles with "created" unix timestamp that matches specific month of the specific year, like April 2014.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers.

EDIT: Thank you all for your effort, and yes, it's unix timestamp.

Comment: Is it a unix timestamp or a BSON date?

Answer (score 1):

How did you create the Unix Timestamp? How is it represented in the document?
Are you using the `MongoDate` type, or are you using an `integer`?

If you are using the `MongoDate` type then you need to construct `MongoDate` objects and use them for your `$gte` and `$lt` conditions

```
$article = array(
    "title"     => "My first article",
    "content"   => "This is good news",
    "published" => new MongoDate(),
    "author"    => "Random guy on the internet",
);

$collection->insert($article);

$start = new MongoDate(strtotime("yesterday"));
$end   = new MongoDate(strtotime("tomorrow"));

$cursor = $collection->find(array("ts" => array('$gt' => $start, '$lte' => $end)));

foreach($cursor as $article) {
    var_dump($article);
}
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php for more info

Answer (score 0):

you'll have build your own query:

`SELECT * FROM news WHERE created >= $start_date AND created <= $end_date`

*where:*

assuming created is unix timestamp, otherwise you should skip `strtotime` function

```
// first day of april 2014
$start_date = strtotime(date('2014-04-01'));

// last day of april 2014
$end_date = strtotime(date('2014-04-t'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to create your timestamps.

```
$begin = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m', '2014-04');
$end = clone $begin;
$end->modify('next month');

echo $begin->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'). PHP_EOL; // 2014-04-01 00:00:00
echo $end->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');            // 2014-05-01 00:00:00
```

And build more complex [condition](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.sqltomongo.php).

```
collection("news")
    ->find(["created" => array(
        '$gte' => $begin->getTimestamp(), 
        '$lt' => $end->getTimestamp())]);
```

Comment: Thank you sectus. This is kinda working, meaning that find() picks up only $gte and displays items created after certain date. The $lt and/or array() is completely ignored.
Both $begin and $end are correctly defined.